# Can I say that an online platform or a Facebook group feels lonesome to me?

Tags: word-usage

Can I say that an online platform or a Facebook group feels lonesome to me?
Every time I log in, I find only a few people online and there aren't that many posts.

Comment: _You_ feel lonesome/lonely when you log on - the platform doesn't.

Comment: @Kate Thanks you for taking the time and answering my questions. Can I say this instead: I feel lonesome in this platform because there aren't many peopled logged in

Comment: Yes - that's what my comment was intended to suggest.

Comment: Any place you go can feel lonesome or you can feel lonesome anywhere, anytime. That said, lonesome means lonely and I don't think you mean that, do you? I feel all alone is better.

Comment: @KateBunting Technically true but pedantic. People often say that a physical place "feels lonesome". Like, "This house feels lonesome since you left." Yes, of course what they really mean is that they feel lonesome in the house, not that the house has feelings.

Comment: @Lambie That depends. That's why it's a "feeling". Usually when I am alone I feel untroubled and content. But sometimes I feel lonesome. It depends on my mood. If when he logs in to this platform he notices that he's the only one logged in and this gives him a feeling of freedom from interruptions or distraction, than he is simply alone. But if he was hoping for people to interact with, he might feel lonesome. Depends what he's trying to say.

Comment: @Jay The word lonesome is a bit corny. We just say: feel alone or lonely. It is a very American word.

Comment: @Lambie Who is "we" here? If you mean that the word "lonesome" is mostly limited to America, maybe so, I don't know. But it's a pretty common word in America. It is widely understood and is considered "normal speech". At least among people that I speak with.

Comment: @Jay We is English speakers, though I am an AmE speaker.  I personally never say lonesome: it makes me think of cowboys (Lonesome Cowboys, film, main characters both southerners), country western music and southerners. Which is fine but regional, as it were.

Comment: @Lambie Well, I haven't done a study of this and I don't know a source to check. I grew up in New York, spent most of my life in Ohio, and presently live in Michigan, and among people I talk to "lonesome" is a perfectly good and normal word. If your experience is different ... I just don't know what to attribute the difference to.

Comment: @Jay Do you say: I'm going to call my friend because I feel lonely and want to talk. Or do you say lonesome there? I would not.

Comment: @Lambie I would say "lonely" in that sentence also. But I would expect someone to say, "I feel lonesome since my wife died", probably not "lonely". (Though that would also work.)

Comment: It's partly regional but where there are two synonyms or two versions of a word, a lot will depend on custom and who/what you listen to and read. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/alone-lonely-or-lonesome) just says lonesome is American. [Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/usage/lonely-lonesome/) suggests lonesome is more profound and long-lasting. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lonesome) suggests lonesome is more poignant. I'm not sure if that's an attempt to create a distinction or is genuinely based on data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, certainly. Just as a physical place can feel lonesome, a "virtual place" could feel lonesome.